# Azure Active Directory in Spring App Without Boot

Tags: spring, azure-active-directory, azure-java-sdk

I have been trying to set up a Spring Web application to use Azure Active Directory.
All the samples that I have found online are based on Spring Boot, is there a simple example that shows setting up spring framework web app only without using Spring Boot?

I am having no luck finding stuff, I am also trying to figure out how to convert all the spring boot autoconfig. Surely there is a sample somewhere that makes it easy to use for a Spring Framework only web-app?

Comment: There are no official samples for this. Azure Functions combined with the Open API example seems like a possible solution though. https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out somewhat. I'm very new to OAuth so still trying to learn as I go.

Basically I followed the Spring Reference and got things working using the override auto-configuration sections at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html

It also helped that I updated the Spring Framework versions to the latest and made sure I used the correct dependencies according to that reference site